# Texture mapping with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to map a texture on a quad using three.js, but something appears to be wrong with the texture coordinates because all I see is the upper-left pixel of the image (UV = {0, 0} everywhere I guess)...

Here is how I define the geometry:

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(-100,  50, 0)));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(-100,  -50, 0)));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(0,  -50, 0)));
geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(0,  50, 0)));
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3));
geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push([new THREE.Vector2(0, 0),
                            new THREE.Vector2(10, 0),
                            new THREE.Vector2(10, 10)]);
geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push([new THREE.Vector2(0, 0),
                            new THREE.Vector2(10, 10),
                            new THREE.Vector2(0, 10)]);
//I also tried:
//geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push([new THREE.Vector2(0, 0),
//                            new THREE.Vector2(10, 0),
//                            new THREE.Vector2(10, 10),
//                            new THREE.Vector2(0, 0),
//                            new THREE.Vector2(10, 10),
//                            new THREE.Vector2(0, 10)]);
geom.computeCentroids();
geom.computeFaceNormals();
```

Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution 2 minutes after posting the question... I need to use new THREE.UV instead of THREE.Vector2.
I really wish the documentation of this project would get a little thicker... Every little thing takes hours of trial and error for now (at least for me)!

Comment: THREE.UV is deprecated and you should indeed use THREE.Vector2.